# Is there a way to forbid column dragging with wx.ListCtrl (wxpython)?

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

[image]

As you can see, you can switch columns by dragging the header of a column to another position, and both `wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG` and `wx.EVT_LIST_COL_BEGIN_DRAG` have no control over this, so is there a way to forbid user dragging columns?

Comment: I think dragging is provided by a mix-in as it is not the default function of listcntr.  So, remove Mixin in __init__ which should look like `listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)`.

Comment: Have you tried using `event.Veto()` on drag events?

Comment: @otterb: No it's not provided by that mix-in. Actually `wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG` should work, but it doesn't seem to trigger anything, and the event ended up sitting in `_controls_.wxEVT_COMMAND_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG` in which `_controls_.pyd` is actually a compiled library, there must be something wrong with the source file used for compile into this pyd.